# How to keep autocomplete event active on Xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I've an xpages in which i set some fields to filter documents, with an autocomplete in one of these.

At the end, a button make a pdf based on this query fields (onClick action), and the pdf is presented to be saved or open.

Ad this point, autocomplete doesn't work anymore, i need to reload the xpage to make autocomplete active again, but i loose all other field values set in previous search.

Is it possible to keep autocomplete alive?

Comment: Hi, I use autocomplete in many of my XPage applications but i havn't seen any of these issues yet =), please could you provide some code? Would help track down your problem.

Comment: Thanks Michael, i'll try to explain.

Comment: my field is a classic full "type ahead"

Comment: this is the button code [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b13d2b09ff9a514f07a4)

Comment: please add complete XP source of that button. I want to know whether it is partial or full (or none refresh).

Comment: Thanks Frantisek, here the code [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a49995321b2c451f42d1)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you serve up an PDF directly from the page and no in a separate window. This will make the XPage to stall and will wait for a timeout of some kind.

I usually on the pdf generation button add this on a js timeout.

XSP.allowSubmit()

That usually works in the cases I have encountered.

Comment: Sorry Fredrik, what do you mean with "js timeout"?

Comment: Thanks but, i doesn't work! ....this is the code in button client JS 'setTimeout(function(){XSP.allowSubmit()},1000)'

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Just set the type ahead mode to **Partial** instead of **Full**

Thanks everyone